# auto and decltype in for loop initialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, auto, decltype

I've been happily iterating like

```
for( auto n = object.get_size(), i = decltype( n )( 0 ); 
     i < n; 
     ++i 
) { ... }
```

to get all the types automagically right. Using g++ 4.7.1 there was no problem, but with version 4.7.0 I got errors. Since 4.7.1 is pretty new, I want to know which version implements the bug and which one the standard. Also, 4.7.0 (as well as 4.6.3 with std=c++0x) only complains when used in conjunction with template, and generates different errors in different usages. See the following code:

```
/* test.cxx */
#ifdef V1

#ifdef GENERIC
template< class T >
void do_some( T obj ) {
    for( auto n = obj, i = decltype( n )( 0 );
             i < n; ++i ) { }
}
#endif

#ifdef SPECIFIC
void do_some( int obj ) {
    for( auto n = obj, i = decltype( n )( 0 );
             i < n; ++i ) { }
}
#endif

#endif

#ifdef V2
template< class T >
class foo {
    T member;
public:
    foo( T stuff ) : member( stuff ) {}
    T get_member() { return member; }
};

#ifdef GENERIC
template< class T >
void do_some( T obj ) {
    for( auto n = obj.get_member(), i = decltype( n )( 0 );
             i < n; ++i ) { }
}
#endif

#ifdef SPECIFIC
void do_some( foo< int > obj ) {
    for( auto n = obj.get_member(), i = decltype( n )( 0 );
             i < n; ++i ) { }
}
#endif

#endif



int main() {
    #ifdef V1
    int foo_inst = 10;
    #endif

    #ifdef V2
    foo< int > foo_inst( 10 );
    #endif

    do_some( foo_inst );

    return 0;
}
```

and the output of g++ version 4.7.0

```
$ g++-4.7 -DV1 -DGENERIC -std=c++11 test.cxx 
test.cxx: In function ‘void do_some(T)’:
test.cxx:7:42: error: inconsistent deduction for ‘auto’: ‘T’ and then ‘decltype (n)’
$ g++-4.7 -DV1 -DSPECIFIC -std=c++11 test.cxx 
/* compiles fine */
$ g++-4.7 -DV2 -DGENERIC -std=c++11 test.cxx 
test.cxx: In function ‘void do_some(T)’:
test.cxx:35:55: error: variable ‘auto n’ with ‘auto’ type used in its own initializer
$ g++-4.7 -DV2 -DSPECIFIC -std=c++11 test.cxx 
/* compiles fine */
```

Comment: Is there some reason why you needed the decltype and the cast operation in there? Can't you just set it equal to zero? It's an integral type; 0 always works for any integral type.

Comment: no the decltype is needed. consider `for( auto n = obj.get_size(), i = 0; ... )`. If `get_size()` returns for example a `long int` (or anything else than an `int`) the compiler complains about an inconsistent deduction for `auto`, which is a good thing, because it could be equally likely that we wanted to implicitly convert `obj.get_size()` to an `int` instead of the other way around - so this would be ambigous... You _can_ make it work by writing `auto n = obj.get_size(); for( decltype( n ) i = 0; ... )`. I just like to group all counting variables in the for brackets...

Comment: It looks like that version of GCC checked the auto too early, in the definition of the template already. There it fails, because "If a decltype specifier involves a template parameter the type denoted by that decltype specifier is a unique dependent type." (freely paraphrased).

Answer (score 1):

No explanations, just test:
I have the same errors as yous for gcc  older than 4.7.1, and no errors from 4.7.1, 4.8 (trunk) and clang-3.2 (trunk)

Comment: thanks for testing, good to know it works in 4.8 and clang. makes me believe it is correct usage and bug of older g++ version